# How do I remove many different parenthesis [] () {} and content from a string using REGEX with a single preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Currently I'm using

```
$str = preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/", "", $str); // Remove () and Content
$str = preg_replace("/\[[^\)]+\]/", "", $str); // Remove [] and Content
$str = preg_replace("/\{[^\)]+\}/", "", $str); // Remove {} and Content
$str = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $str);  // Remove all non-alphanumeric characters
```

I was wondering if there was a way to combine these into a single regex statement

Comment: Even without combining into one regex, preg_replace can take arrays as its first 2 parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `|` to combine those:

```
(\([^\)]+\)|\[[^\]]+\]|\{[^\}]+\})|[^A-Za-z0-9])
```

---

But in your case, I would usually just go through the string and parse it manually.
With "state variables" (`$paren_open`, `$brace_open`, `$curly_open`) to know if you ignore the char or not.

Even if it doesn't seem fast (because you have to go through every character), it's much quicker than regexes, because the regex will do something way more complicated.

---

**Resources:**

- [Wikipedia: State pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)

Comment: I don't know if it's faster, but I'm sure that state machines are easier to code and way more reliable.

Comment: It will be faster, for a simple reason, here we go through the String only once and do basically nothing. A regex would have to go through the String too, but it has also the "expression part" to do, which is way more complicated than checking 3 variables.

Comment: `\W` is not the same as `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`, as `\w` includes `_`.

Comment: @cbuckley, indeed, but I was too lazy to copy the whole `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` part in an already unreadable regex. (fixed ;P) Anyway this regex shouldn't be used, the other solution is much more performant.

Comment: $str = preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)|\[[^\]]+\]|\{[^\}]+\}|[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $str);

This solution worked for me very well, thanks Colin :)

I'll also look up "state variables", the description didn't seem to make a lot of sense, but I'm sure if I look it up I'll be able to use it in the future.  Thank you

Comment: @iNk, I can't insist enough on the fact that the regex here is a bad idea performance wise.